# Android - Is there a way to know when a user adds a new contact to his phone?

Tags: android, android-intent, contacts

I was wondering if there exists a way (an intent or such) to know each time the user adds a new contact to his contacts list.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [ContentObserver](https://www.google.com.bd/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html&ei=AiN0UfbWKYiIrQfS_oCICg&usg=AFQjCNFXwFGxVOY49yjkipyZXo_OSIfNIQ&sig2=AtC9M7iZCLKS2BvW78LcSw&bvm=bv.45512109,d.bmk) to be notified when a change is made in the content provider. The followings can be used to know about the change of contact book

Declare a content Observer

```
private final ContentObserver contentObserver = new ContentObserver(null) {

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
                  super.onChange(selfChange);
                  perform your task;
            }
    }
```

Register the observer with android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI to be notified about contact change

```
    this.getApplicationContext()
            .getContentResolver()
            .registerContentObserver(
                    android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                    true, contentObserver);
```

Dont forget to unregister it in onDestroy

```
    this.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver()
            .unregisterContentObserver(contentObserver);
```

Whenever there is a change in the system phonebook you will be notified via onChange callback method.

But one problem is you will be notified not only for add, but also for any change (edit/delete). I am not sure is there any specific easy way ( as a worst way you can track the contacts by yourself) for that.